# Modification time is not updating in magnolia

Tags: magnolia

I am uploading the images and videos in magnolia stk resources module it uploading sucessfully.

when updating or modifying the resources the maodfication date is not updating it remains same as the first uploading time.

Can anyone suggest how to update the modification date

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Look at `mgnl:lastModified` property of the node you have updated.

e.g. on [demo](http://demoauthor.magnolia-cms.com) from groovy console:

```
mgnl> dam = ctx.getJCRSession("dam"); dam.getNode("/tours/flickr-surfer-mandolin-373088839_7da451ccc8_b.jpg").getProperty("mgnl:lastModified").string
====> 2015-06-02T15:04:05.724+02:00
```

HTH,
Jan